# Django custom form with widget

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using a custom form (which is not a ModelForm) and I am trying to plug that nicely into the django interface. The issue is that the layout of the form is not the same as a 'regular admin form' and that I can't make the widgets work.

I am using:

- django 1.9
- python 3.5
- django-selectable
- django-suit

Right now I get correctly the form displayed, but it is not typesetted as another form would be and the autocomplete widget is not working

Here is my template code:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}
    {{ form }}
{% endblock %}
```

admin.py file:

```
class UsersInEventAdmin(ExportMixin):
    list_display = ('user', 'event', 'options_selected', 'payed', 'user_phone',
                    'user_email', 'user_have_certificate')
    list_filter = ('event__name', 'payed')
    search_fields = ["^event__name",
                     "^user__user__first_name",
                     "^user__user__last_name"]
    ordering = ["event__name", "user__user__last_name",
                "user__user__first_name"]

    form = SportifInEventAdminForm

    # Extend for prefilled forms
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(UsersInEventAdmin, self).get_urls()
        my_urls = [
            url(r'^([0-9]+)/foo/$',
                self.admin_site.admin_view(self.event_registration_form))
        ]
        return my_urls + urls

    def event_registration_form(self, request, event):
        # Populate the options for the event
        options = [
            dict(description=e.description,
                 choices=[(-1, 'Aucun')]+[
                     (c.id, c.description)
                     for c in EventOptionChoice.objects.filter(option=e)
                 ])
            for e in EventOption.objects.filter(event_id=event)]

        # Parse the request
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print('Got a form!')
            form = UserInEventGenericForm(request.POST, event_options=options)
            if form.is_valid():
                # Save the form
                # TODO
                # Return the form once again
                form = UserInEventGenericForm(event_options=options)
        else:
            print('creating new form')
            form = UserInEventGenericForm(event_options=options)

        request.form = form
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        data = {
            'form': form,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'change': False,
            'is_popup': False,
            'save_as': False,
            'has_delete_permission': True,
            'has_add_permission': False,
            'has_change_permission': False
        }
        return render(request,
                      "admin/event_registration_form.html",
                      data,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and my forms.py:

```
class UserInEventGenericForm(forms.Form):
    '''Dynamically generate a form for given set of questions'''
    user = forms.CharField(label='User',
                           widget=AutoCompleteSelectWidget(SportifLookup),
                           required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if "event_options" in kwargs:
            options = kwargs.pop('event_options')
        else:
            options = []

        super(UserInEventGenericForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['user'].widget = AutoCompleteSelectWidget(
            lookup_class=SportifLookup)
        for i, option in enumerate(options):
            self.fields['option_%s' % i] = forms.ChoiceField(
                choices=option['choices'],
                label=option['description'])
```

UPDATE:
Here's a screenshot of what I have:
[image: the wrong form]